# Why are some posts highlighted yellow?

Tags: support, status-completed, design, bookmarks

At the risk of looking stupid, why are some of the posts highlighted yellow?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The yellow highlighted questions are those that contain one of your favorite tags. You can edit the tags on your GIS SE home page by selecting the "edit" hyperlink. Note that in addition to adding favorite tags, you can add ignore tags, which will grey out questions.

Comment: Oh yes! That's so obvious now you have pointed that out. Thanks

Comment: That's what I thought, but I couldn't figure out this scenario (screenshot at: https://www.screencast.com/t/naHJyYuZ51) - notice that only one or two are highlighted, when FME is a favourite tag. But now it occurs that when looking at a particular tag, SE is only showing in yellow where another tag is also a favourite. That's rather smart - although it's always been a puzzle until I looked at it again.

Comment: Oh, I see that's interesting, that's another layer to this that I hadn't noticed, thanks